# How to delete cached/intermediate docker images after the cache gets invalidated?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, docker-image

I have a CI-pipeline that builds a docker image for my app for every run of the pipeline (and the pipeline is triggered by a code-push to the git repository.)

The docker image consists of several intermediate layers which progressively become very large in size. Most of the intermediate images are identical for each run, hence the caching mechanism of docker is significantly utilized.

However, the problem is that the final couple layers are different for each run, as they result from a COPY statement in dockerfile, where the built application artifacts are copied into the image. Since the artifacts are modified for every run, the already cached bottommost images will ALWAYS be invalidated. These images have a size of 800mb each.

What docker command can I use to identify (and delete) these image that gets replaced by newer images, i.e. when they get invalidated?

I would like to have my CI-pipeline to remove them at the end of the run so they don't end up dangling on the CI-server and waste a lot of disk space.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If I understand correctly: With every code push, CI pipeline creates new image, where new version of application is deployed. As a result, previously created image becomes outdated, so you want to remove it. To do so, you have to:

1. Get rid of all outdated containers, which where created from outdated image

- display all containers with command `docker ps -a`
- if still running, stop outdated containers with command `docker stop [containerID]`
- remove them with `command docker rm [containerID]`

2. Remove outdated images with command: `docker rmi [imageID]`

To sum up why this process is needed: you cannot remove any image, until it is used by any existing container (even stopped containers still require their images). For this reason, you should first stop and remove old containers, and then remove old images.

Detection part, and automation of deletion process should be based on image versions and container names, which CI pipeline generates while creating new images.

**Edit 1**

To list all images, which have no relationship to any tagged images, you can use command: `docker images -f dangling=true`. You can delete them with the command: `docker images purge`.

Just one thing to remember here: If you build an image without tagging it, the image will appear on the list of "dangling" images. You can avoid this situation by providing a tag when you build it.

**Edit 2**

The command for image purging has changed. Right now the proper command is:

```
docker image prune
```

Here is a [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) with a documentation

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

The problem here is not that there exists containers using the images. In fact, the pipeline succesfully removes all containers (using docker-compose down) at the end of the run.

The challenge is in identifying which layers of the image has been used from cache, and which have been invalidated with the new build.

Comment: For Instance, let's say I have an image
myrepo.com/myapp:1.

Now this is built using a dockerfile that contains several docker commands, thus yielding an intermediate image per command. 

When I then build the same image the second time, it will reuse all non-modified images from cache. In my case, that is ALL images except the two bottommost ones. How do I then make sure that the pipeline deletes these two images from the previous run?

Comment: I think that perfectly answers my question :)

The key here is:  "which have no relationship to any tagged images". But just to confirm:
If I have images X,Y and Z, where Z is based on Y and Y is based on X, and only image Z is tagged.
 
Then come along images Y2 and Z2, where Y2 is based on X (cached), and Z2 is based on Y2, and now image Z and Z2 is tagged.

So:

X -> Y -> Z*
X -> Y2 -> Z2*

*tagged

When I then run `docker images purge`, according to my understanding, the only image that will be removed is Y. Is that correct? If so, then that's exactly the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks very much :) I should have probably read up on "dangling" images thoroughly

Comment: Looks like now we should use `docker image prune` instead of `docker images purge`

Comment: > To sum up why this process is needed: you cannot remove any image, until it is used by any existing container


Do you mean "unused by any existing container"?