# Is there a way to clean docker build cache?

Tags: macos, docker

I am running a lot of builds using Docker in MacOS. Eventually, a lot of build cache is accumulating, e.g. this is what I see in `docker system df`:

```
YPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          22        0         9.67GB    9.67GB (100%)
Containers      0         0         0B        0B
Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B
Build Cache     1006      0         258GB     258GB
```

Is there a way to clean items from the build cache? I can see detailed list of them, e.g.:

```
CACHE ID       CACHE TYPE     SIZE      CREATED             LAST USED           USAGE     SHARED
045834a7a6e9   regular        11.1MB    3 weeks ago                             0         false
114ca5b7280f   regular        114MB     3 weeks ago                             0         false
27d6fcbb531d   regular        1.65kB    3 weeks ago                             0         false
3042a2a59d4f   regular        553kB     3 weeks ago                             0         false
3d70c1a312eb   regular        468MB     3 weeks ago                             0         false
658aaefc4cdd   regular        209MB     3 weeks ago                             0         false
7d5b48149871   regular        59.9MB    3 weeks ago                             0         false
86569a54d5d4   regular        16.5MB    3 weeks ago                             0         false
```

etc. with `docker system df -v` but the only way I see to remove any is completely wiping all Docker data, including images, etc. which I don't want to do. Is there any other way to make Docker to reclaim the space? I can see those objects but I can find no way of deleting them...

P.S.1 This question is **not** about how to delete images and containers. I know how to delete them, unfortunately deleting either does nothing to the "Build Cache" contents which continues to occupy space.

P.S.2 This is especially important on MacOS because there Docker operates within one specific allocated volume, which this way gets exhausted very quickly and I start getting "out of disk space" errors when building. Since the builds are done repeatedly, keeping data from old builds is not useful for me, so finding a way to delete old build caches would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete cached/intermediate docker images after the cache gets invalidated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51612208/how-to-delete-cached-intermediate-docker-images-after-the-cache-gets-invalidated)

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I know how to delete images and containers. This is specifically for *build cache* - which as you can see is separate item in the `df` output, and a huge one at that.

Comment: Try this [https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/builder_prune/](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/builder_prune/)

Comment: @Ishan yes! This seems to work, reduced build cache from 258G to mere 37G, which looks much saner. Though I do not see this space reclaimed (Docker desktop still shows same disk usage) I think it might be the solution. Could you add it as an answer so I could approve it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
docker builder prune
```

Removes build cache. Docs: [`docker builder prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/builder_prune/)

Comment: The --all made a difference. Without it, it did not work. (On OsX)

Comment: In my case after image pruned, docker restart helped completely wipe caches.

Answer (score 40):

```
docker builder prune --all
```

more details: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/builder_prune/